# react-native-firebase phone register custom url doesn't seem to work

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm struggling with implementing phone verification in react-native.

I did all stuff what docs said.

But i keep getting this error.

I already registered custom url with reversed-client-id in GoogleService-info.plist.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's about version issue.

I was using RN 0.59.1 and now I upgraded to RN 0.61.5

So I should have upgraded react native firebase to optimize to new version.